# Get DateTime from Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am saving date and times in Mysql (in the save column) and now I am trying to make a plot using date and time and temperature. I'm using:

```
DateTime tm = myReader.GetDateTime("dateandtime");
```

(`dateandtime` is saved to the database and contains, for example, `15.04.2015 10:55:35`).

My problem is when I try to make the graphic this error comes up:

**"input string was not in a correct format"**

And I don't know how to fix it.
I tried to only write the date (ex 15.04.2015) to the database and it works, but I want the complete date and time to be saved.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

```
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";           
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from test.edata;", conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                DateTime tm = myReader.GetDateTime("dataandtime");                    
                double tempbd = myReader.GetDouble("temperatura");
                //DateTime tr = Convert.ToDateTime(tm);
                listbd.Add(tm.ToOADate(), tempbd);
            }
            zedGraphControl2.AxisChange();
            zedGraphControl2.Refresh();
            zedGraphControl2.Invalidate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I don't understand why on my X axis i have only Minute:Second :(.I add a breakpoint and the "tm" variable show the complete date and time ,but on my plot i have only minute and second

Comment: Can you please show the relevant C# code throws that exception?

Comment: dd.MM.yyyy is an odd format are you storing it as a string? try DateTime.ParseExact https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What is the type of this `dateandtime` column?

Comment: the type for dateandtime is varchar

Comment: Why do you save your `DateTime` values as a `varchar`? This is the root problem.

Comment: I change the type,but when i read data from serial port and i try to save in DB the dateandtime is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 every time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `GetDateTime` method takes zero based column number as an `int`. That's why, your code does not *even* compile. You will need to use it as;

```
DateTime tm = myReader.GetDateTime(3);
```

Second of all, `GetDateTime` does not performing any conversation, that's why your column value must be already a `DateTime` object.

I *strongly* suspect you try to save your `DateTime` values as a character. Please don't do that. Use proper column types always.

Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

You need to change your column type to [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html) first, insert your `DateTime` values directly to your parameterized queries and use `GetDateTime` method with the number of it's ordinal when you try to get them in your database.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and readers.

Comment: i use DateTime  tm = myReader.GetDateTime(3) but i have the same problem.

Comment: @Ade You need to change your column type first and use this method.

Comment: I change the type,but when i read data from serial port and i try to save in DB the dateandtime is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 every time.

Comment: I don't understand why on my X axis i have only Minute:Second :(.I add a breakpoint and the "tm" variable show the complete date and time ,but on my plot i have only minute and second.

Comment: @Ade How do you insert your `DateTime` exactly? Did you change your column type?

Comment: I solved!Thanks a lot!Now i want to create a button to refresh the graph:)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use DateTime.Now;

Comment: That response hasn't any context and it's difficult to be valuable to solve the problem. Explain the existing problem and how your solution fix it. Put yourself in the questioner's shoes